# Data won't appear: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, slice

I'm trying to display some data from an API but I'm receiving an error. I was able to print it to the console but not onto the web page as HTML. The error I'm receiving is: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined. I don't want to use slice however I'm not sure how to display the data without using slice either. How can I display this data without using slice? The data is in an object

```
// The first section of data from the API - showing the data structure
{
"id": 1,
"url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome",
"name": "Under the Dome",
"type": "Scripted",
"language": "English",
"genres": [
"Drama",
"Science-Fiction",
"Thriller"
],
"status": "Ended",
"runtime": 60,
"premiered": "2013-06-24",
"officialSite": "http://www.cbs.com/shows/under-the-dome/",
"schedule": {
"time": "22:00",
"days": [
"Thursday"
]
},
```

```
// Printing the data to the console
//fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1?embed=episodes') 
//.then((resp) => resp.json()) 
//.then(function (data) {
//   console.log(data)
//})
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1?embed=episodes') 
.then((resp) => resp.json()) 
.then(function (data) {
   const text = document.querySelectorAll(".text")
    data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach((div, i) => { 
    text[i].innerHTML = ` <h2>${div.url}</h2> 
    <p><strong>${div.name}</strong></p>
    `
      }) 
    })
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alatsi|Dancing+Script|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="tv.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="tv.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                    <li class="header"><h1>Entertainment</h1></li>
                    <li><a href="tv.html">TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  </ul>
        <div class="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `data.results` is undefined. What are you hoping to see in `results`?

Comment: there is a possibility api result is not an array of results

Comment: I thought that may be the problem because there is no "results" array so I removed results but I get the same error. @King11

Comment: @Rahni what are you actually trying to slice within the data? Generes?

Comment: I don't want to use slice. I just want to print the name of the TV shows and some more information however I don't know how to remove it and make the code work. If I was to use slice I could slice the tv shows so that the information on each show is separate and I can display a set of information on a certain amount of tv shows. @King11

Comment: Ah ok, let me see what I can do

Comment: You said you have it print correctly within your console, can you show code or a screenshot of how it looks in your console?

Comment: @Rahni ok, thanks. you can delete the screenshots now

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with a screenshot of the data in the console. @King11

Comment: No problem, the first thing is, is that `data` is one huge object. You can't use slice on it to start with because it isn't an array of items. You can slice arrays within `data` such as `generes`. But from what I can tell, for each `episode` within `embeded` you want to display the `url` as a `h2` and the `name` as a `p`? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that is exactly what I'd like to do. @King11

Comment: @Rahni No problem, I'm still working on it. Just trying to figure out how to display the items nicely within the`div`

Comment: @King11 Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your code, you are trying to slice on an object. That won't work because `slice` works on items such as arrays. Also within your html, you have a single `div` class that you want the `innerHTML` changed within each item in the array. Since there is only one `div` with the class `text`, then that `div` will just continuously become overwritten. So `text[i].innerHTML` will not work in that case. What I did on order to bypass that problem, for each item I found in the loop, I created a new `div` element and inserted the data within the newly created `div`. I also took out the `slice` code and I'm looping through each item within the `episodes` array and appending the new `div` to the document's body. Hopefully this helps you get on the right track.

```js
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1?embed=episodes') 
.then((resp) => resp.json()) 
.then(function (data) {
    var embed = data._embedded;
    var epi = embed .episodes;
    epi.forEach((item,i) => {
    var newDivElement = document.createElement('div');
    newDivElement.className = "text";
    newDivElement.innerHTML = ` <h2>${epi[i].url}</h2> 
    <p><strong>${epi[i].name}</strong></p>`
    document.body.appendChild(newDivElement);
    }) 
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alatsi|Dancing+Script|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="tv.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="tv.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                    <li class="header"><h1>Entertainment</h1></li>
                    <li><a href="tv.html">TV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! It has worked and I have learnt more about how to display data from an API now! @King11

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the API is not returning an array in this case, it's just one object. Slice will only work if it is called on an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I display the data without using slice. I just want to display some data (I don't need to slice anything) but I'm not sure how to do so. @MarcusGallegos

Comment: just use data.[whatever property you want]